# Wildcard expansion (globbing) in a string composed of quoted and unquoted parts

Tags: bash, shell, glob, quoting, shopt

I have a line in a shell script that looks like this:

```
java -jar "$dir/"*.jar
```

, since I just want to execute whatever the jar file happens to be named in that folder. But this is not working as I expected. I get the error message:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile [folder-name]/*.jar
```

It is taking the '*' character literally, instead of doing the replacement that I want. How do I fix this?

EDIT: It is working now. I just had the wrong folder prefix :/ For anybody wondering, this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: If there is no file ending with `.jar` in a particular directory `x`, then the result of attempting to expand `x/*.jar` will be `x/*.jar`, which doesn't exist. At least the default in `bash` seems to work that way in most installations. `bash` has a number of options (e.g. `failglob`, `nullglob`, and a few others) to modify the default behavior if that is what you want.

Answer (score 6):

### Explanation and background information

The OP's **problem was NOT with globbing per se** - for a glob (pattern) to work, the **special pattern characters such as `*` must be *unquoted***, which **works even in strings that are *partly* single- or double-quoted**, as the OP correctly did in his question:

```
"$dir/"*.jar # OK, because `*` is unquoted
```

Rather, the problem was `bash`'s - somewhat surprising - **default behavior of leaving a pattern *unexpanded* (leaving it as is), *if it happens not to match anything***, effectively **resulting in a string that does NOT represent any actual filesystem items.**

- In the case at hand, `"$dir"` happened to expand to a directory that did not contain `*.jar` files, and thus the resulting string passed to `java` ended in *literal* `*.jar` (`'<value of $dir>/*.jar'`), which due to not referring to actual `.jar` files, resulted in the error quoted in the question.

**Shell options govern globbing (more formally called *pathname expansion*)**:

- `set -f` (`shopt -so noglob`) **turns off globbing altogether**, so that unquoted strings (characters) that would normally cause a string to be treated as a glob are treated as literals.
- `shopt -s nullglob` alters the default behavior to expanding a **non-matching glob to an *empty string***.
- `shopt -s failglob` alters the default behavior to ***reporting an error and setting the exit code to 1* in the case of a non-matching glob**, without even executing the command at hand - see below for pitfalls.
- There are other globbing-related options not relevant to this discussion - to see a list of all of them, run `{ shopt -o; shopt; } | fgrep glob`. For a description, search by their names in `man bash`.

---

### Robust globbing solutions

Note: **Setting shell options globally affects the current shell**, which is problematic, as third-party code usually makes the - reasonable - assumption that defaults are in effect. Thus, it is **good practice to only change shell options temporarily (change, perform action, restore) or to localize changing their effect by using a subshell (`(...)`)**.

---

`shopt -s nullglob`

- **Useful** for enumerating matches in a loop with `for` - it ensures that the loop is never entered, if there are no matches:

```sh
shopt -s nullglob # expand non-matching globs to empty string
for f in "$dir/"*.jar; do
  # If the glob matched nothing, we never get here.
  # !! Without `nullglob`, the loop would be entered _once_, with 
  # !! '<value of $dir>/*.jar'.
done
```

- **Problematic** when used with arguments to commands that have default behavior in the absence of filename arguments, as it can result in unexpected behavior:

```sh
shopt -s nullglob # expand non-matching globs to empty string
wc -c "$dir/"*.jar # !! If no matches, expands to just `wc -c`
```

If the glob doesn't match anything, just `wc -c` is executed, which does *not* fail, and instead starts reading `stdin` input (when run interactively, this will simply wait for interactive input lines until terminated with <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>).

---

`shopt -s failglob`

- **Useful** for reporting a specific error message, especially when combined with `set -e` to cause automatic aborting of a script in case a glob matches nothing:

```sh
set -e  # abort automatically in case of error
shopt -s failglob # report error if a glob matches nothing
java -jar "$dir/"*.jar  # script aborts, if this glob doesn't match anything
```

- **Problematic** when needing to know the specific cause of an error and when combined with the `|| <command in case of failure>` idiom:

```sh
shopt -s failglob # report error if a glob matches nothing
# !! DOES NOT WORK AS EXPECTED.
java -jar "$dir/"*.jar || { echo 'No *.jar files found.' >&2; exit 1; }
# !! We ALWAYS get here (but exit code will be 1, if glob didn't match anything).
```

Since, with `failglob` on, `bash` never even executes the command at hand if globbing fails, the `||` clause is *also* not executed, and overall execution continues.

While the failed glob will cause the exit code to be set to `1`, you won't be able to distinguish between failure due to a non-matching glob vs. failure reported by the command (after successful globbing).

---

**Alternative solution without changing shell options:**

With a little more effort, you can **do your own checking for non-matching globs**:

**Ad-hoc**:

```sh
glob="$dir/*.jar"
[[ -n $(shopt -s nullglob; echo $glob) ]] || 
  { echo 'No *.jar files found.' >&2; exit 1; }
java -jar $glob
```

`$(shopt -s nullglob; echo $glob)` sets `nullglob` and then expands the glob with `echo`, so that the subshell either returns matching filenames or, if nothing matches, an *empty* string;  that output, thanks to command substitution (`$(...)`), is passed to `-n`, which tests whether the string is empty, so that the overall `[[ ... ]]` conditional's exit code reflects if *something* matched (exit code `0`) or not (exit code `1`).

Note that any command inside a command substitution runs in a *subshell*, which ensures that the effect of `shopt -s nullglob` only applies to that very subshell and thus doesn't alter global state.

Also note how the *entire* right-hand side in the variable assignment `glob="$dir/*.jar"` is double-quoted, to illustrate the point that quoting with respect to globbing matters when a variable is *referenced later*, not when it is *defined*. The *unquoted references* to `$glob` later ensure that the entire string is interpreted as a glob.

**With a small helper function**:

```sh
# Define simple helper function.
exists() { [[ -e $1 ]]; }

glob="$dir/*.jar"
exists $glob || { echo 'No *.jar files found.' >&2; exit 1; }
java -jar $glob
```

The helper function takes advantage of shell applying globbing *upon invocation* of the function, and passing the *results* of globbing (pathname expansion) as arguments. The function then simply tests whether the 1st resulting argument (if any), refers to an *existing* item, and sets the exit code accordingly (this will work regardless of whether `nullglob` happens to be in effect or not).

Answer (score 5):

You just need to set `failglob`:

```
shopt -s failglob
```

to avoid showing literal `*.jar` when none are matched in a given folder.

**PS:** This will generate an error when it fails to match any `*.jar` as:

```
-bash: no match: *.jar
```

Comment: `shopt`: Set and unset shell options.

Comment: I would think `failglob` might be more appropriate here, as running `java -jar` is probably not a desirable outcome of a failed expansion. Although either way, you just git a failure message of some sort, I guess...

Comment: @twalberg: Agreed. While you do get error messages in both cases (at least in this case), only the one you get with `failglob` will indicate the _immedate_ problem (`bash: no match: *.jar`). With `nullglob`, the command may _not_ fail in other cases and result in unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have `bash` shell installed to use the command `shopt` described by  @mklement0